# Customer's request

Tags: articles, possessives

I know that **customer** is a countable noun. Can you explain me why in these sentences an author uses different articles:

- We can also customize fairways according to **customer's request**/Site support (provided by **customer's request**) - Site support includes daily or weekly translation of texts published at the website.
- At **the** customer's request, we manufacture welded wires of galvanised wire.

Maybe the possessive noun **"customer's"** plays a role of *adjective* in the two first sentences? Or an author just wanted to generalize the meaning of the collocation. I will be happy to receive your explanation!

Comment: Probably a mistake.  If this comes from https://minigolfas.com/en/production/ (as google suggests) its a European (Lithuanian) website, and there are little minor errors in the English.  If it is not from there, then where is the source of the quote?

Comment: The source is reverso context. By the way, I found similar examples in the Cambridge dictionary: Sea urchin roe is considered a delicacy and it is used (at customer request) to add strength to ceviche/ Such a list is generated by broker-dealers based on reasonable assurance that the securities on the list are readily available upon customer request.

Comment: I also want to inquire about the phrase "at/upon request". The same situation: I found different examples of the use of these phrases. For instance: Image removed at request of owner/I'm here at the request of your manager; In this case upon request of the applicants a certificate of the standard form is issued/Conduct of trade efficiency assessment upon the request of individual countries. Are all these sentences correct?

Comment: reverso context is full of random stuff.  It's not a proper source.  I think this is just Lithuanian bad grammar.  The Cambridge example is different, the word "customer" is acting as modifier,  a noun adjunct that describes what kind of request and may even function as a determiner - at this point I normally hope that BillJ will fill in the proper grammar words

Comment: Thanks for explanation!